# mdtable datasource changes doesn't update de view

Tags: angular, datasource, two-way-binding

I have a Mdtable like this:

https://plnkr.co/edit/a9JKUnVxeYwjNeH067qZ?p=preview

When I make change to dataSource, for example, slice to list. Object changes, but view doesn't update.

In my real code, I solved this issue emtying the datasource matching to null, refill the model, call changeDetectRef and finally initializing datasource again.

```
this.datasource = null;
// changes to model
this.ref.detectChanges();
setDatatable(); //Initilize datasource
```

I don't believe that there is no other simpler solution, I'm forgetting something?

P.D. I found some information that talks about "push" to two way binding lifecyle , but it does not explain it very well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a new solution:

```
  const copiedData = this.dataSource._exampleDatabase.dataChange._value.slice(0,3);
  this.dataSource._exampleDatabase.dataChange.next(copiedData);
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/AJjknAbl42KSbIaRjI86?p=preview

Thanks